# Magento: How to avoid indexing of a store view?

Tags: magento, search-engine

I have 2 store views in my store. Is it possible to only have one of them indexed by Google & Co? The other one should be completely ignored. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Goto magento admin -> System ->Configuration and select store view from the configuration scope and then in "Design" section change value of "Default Robots" to "NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW" and save your configuration.

Comment: well the problem is that menu is greyed on a store view